# Uses “Recursion” concept to iterate collection data in Functional Programming

Tags: loops, oop, recursion, functional-programming

I read some papers and documents that said that Functional Programming uses “recursion” concept to iterate collection data, while OOP uses “loop” concept to iterate collection data (for example:- the for-each loop in Java). So I'm confused about that statement. And I have three questions

- Is it a good practice when I use “loop” in Functional Programming?
- If not, can anyone tell me what method I should use?
- Can anyone give me an example and comparison about two methods of iterating Collection Data?

Comment: _Transferred from the answer:_ By the way, welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). 

This question is somewhat open ended, and falls outside the scope of the traditional SO format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is somewhat unclear, for instance

> Is it a good practice when I use “loop” in Functional Programming?

What would a loop construct be inside a functional programming language? Several functional programming languages lack explicit loop statements (for-each, for, while, do-while, ...)

---

Regardless, in order:

> Is it a good practice when I use “loop” in Functional Programming?

Any attempt to express a loop using an imperative style is usually considered as a poor practice. As previously stated, many functional programming (FP) languages lack such constructs.

> If not, can anyone tell me what method I should use?

You can read about [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) at Wikipedia.

Many data structures, such as lists, are recursive by nature so iterating across them recursively should feel rather natural.

> Can anyone give me an example and comparison about two methods of iterating collection data?

Let's us iterate across a list using some pseudo-code,

### Imperative style

A couple of imperative examples that map to different looping constructs.

#### For-each

```
list = [1, 2, 3]

for element in list:
    print element
```

#### While

Let `len` be a function that returns the length of the list, and let lists be zero-indexed, so that `list[0] == 1`,

```
list = [1, 2, 3]
i = 0

while i < len(list):
    print element
    i++
```

### Functional style

Using recursion:

Let `head(list)` be a function that returns the first element of the list and `tail(list)` return all elements after the head

```
list = [1, 2, 3]

def loop(list):
   if list == []: # Check if the list is empty
       return

   print head(list)
   loop(tail(list))
```

There are other ways to iterate across lists in many FP languages, most notably `map` and list-comprehensions but I'll leave that out for now.